# PostgreSQL Concat 2 numbers gives me error

Tags: sql, postgresql, object-to-string

I'm trying to concat 2 numbers from two different columns, those are chain_code and shop_code.

[image]

I tried this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(`shop_code`, `shop_code`) AS myid FROM {table}
```

But I get an error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: ` integer
LINE 1: SELECT CONCAT(`shop_code`, `shop_code`) AS myid FROM...
                  ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I even tried to convert it to string but couldn't `... CONCAT(to_char(chain_code, '999')...) ...` but it says there is no such a function called 'to_sting' (found on [PostgreSQL Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-formatting.html))

Answer (score 3):

First: do not use those dreaded backticks `` ` `` , that's invalid (standard) SQL.

To quote an identifier use double quotes: `"shop_code"`, **not** `` `shop_code` ``

But as those identifiers don't need any quoting, just leave them out completely. In general you should avoid using quoted identifiers. They cause much more trouble than they are worth it.

For details on specifying SQL identifiers see the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

But `concat()` only works on text/varchar values, so you first need to convert/cast the integer values to varchar:

```
SELECT CONCAT(chain_code::text, shop_code::text) AS myid FROM...
```

---

> *but it says there is no such a function called 'to_sting'*

Well, the function is `to_char()`, not `to_sting()`.

Using `to_char()` is an alternative to the cast operator `::text` but is a bit more complicated in this case:

```
SELECT CONCAT(to_char(chain_code,'999999'), to_char(shop_code, '999999')) AS myid FROM...
```

The problem with `to_string()` in this context is, that you need to specify a format mask that can deal with all possible values in that column. Using the cast operator is easier and just as good.

---

**Update** (thanks mu)

As mu is to short pointed out, concat doesn't actually need any cast or conversion:

```
SELECT CONCAT(chain_code, shop_code) AS myid FROM...
```

will work just fine.

---

Here is an SQLFiddle showing all possible solutions: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2ab82/3

Comment: PostgreSQL's `concat` will apply the casts by itself: ["Concatenate the text representations of all the arguments."](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-string.html). Assuming of course that you have 9.1 or higher so that you have a `concat` function at all.

Comment: @muistooshort: thanks, I added that as well (I keep forgetting that)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ok, "will work just fine", but it doesn't! I just tried and the result is the same... Maybe is something else

Comment: @Mr.Web: and I was confused: of course it must be `to_char()` **not** `to_string()`